# Get process time of a function VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I need a way to get the time it takes from a WebService (Server Side) to complete a function or a process, is there any simple way to do this?

Im using VB.net and Visual Studio 2017

Comment: It depends on a lot of things, which side you want to do the check (server or client), where you want the information stored, how many times you want it to be called, ect... You can do it with code or with a software. The easiest way is just to look at a watch and execute the method.

Comment: Edited my question, looking for server side and looking to stored it in a txt file i allready got a function for that i only need to store the time in a variable so i can manipulate it

Comment: The [StopWatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2) is made for just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What soohoonigan said

```
Private Function SomeFunction() As Boolean
    Dim stpw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew 'start timing
    '
    '
    '
    '
    'and then
    stpw.Stop() 'stop timing
    '
    ' the stpw.Elapsed property is a timespan

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Hey down voting person, leave a comment telling me how to improve this answer.